# Why web handler is calling two times in a jquery dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net web app in which i am displaying a pdf in a jquery dialog and pdf is in an Iframe.My code is

```
  if (int.Parse(Request.QueryString["option"].ToString()) == 0)
    {
        showPDF(DocumentId, perId);
        mediaRep.MediaViewLog(memberId, DocumentId);
        litScript.Text = "<script>$(function(){$( '#dialog' ).dialog( 'destroy');$(\"#showPdf\").dialog({height: \"auto\",width:\"auto\",modal: true ,buttons:{OK: function () {$(this).dialog(\"close\");window.location=\"PdfSearch.aspx\"}},close:function(){closeDialogPer(\"" + perId + "\");window.location=\"PdfSSearch.aspx\"}});});</script>";
    }

  publicvoid showPDF(Guid DocumentId, int perId)
    {
        litObj.Text = "<iframe  type=\"application/pdf\" class=\"noprint pdfPreviewSettings\" src=\"/Search/GetPdfFile.ashx?MediaId=" + DocumentId + "&FileType=Document" + "&PerId=" + perId +
                                            "\" onclick=\"disableRightClick();\"  width=\"1150\" height=\"750\" ><strong class=\"pdfError \">Please contact your system administrator for installation of adobe acrobat reader.</strong></iframe>";
    }
```

Problem is that when pdf is shown in dialog the web handler in iframe is calling two times and without dialog handler is calling one time.What would be the reason that by using jquery dialog call to handler becomes double and how to fix it.

Comment: Did this happen in a particular Browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE9)?

Comment: no on different browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for 2 requests in case of `dialog` call is that the iframe is on page and already loaded once but the `dialog` call remove the iframe from its current parent element and then append it to some other element (like a div center on page) and this causes the iframe to reload its content and you cannot avoid this problem.

The solution would be to not set the iframe src in the html markup and after you call the dialog function on the iframe then set the iframe src to the url.

```
$("#showPdf").dialog(...);
$("#showPdf").attr("src","<here goes the url to be loaded>");
```